# Install from a .bat file

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, batch-file

I have an old Mecer Notebook, at the school where I work, that is running Windows XP. My Principal has forgotten the password, but has asked me to see if I can get it working. I have tried everything! From trying to bypass the system by using the Default Administrator account(which is disabled or just doesn't exist) to trying to reinstall Windows 7 on the PC.

And herein is my problem...I cannot get the PC to install from the CD. Keep in mind that I cannot access the Desktop because I can't log in...AT ALL!!!! What I wanna know is, is there a way for me to make a CD with a .bat file that will automatically select the Windows 7 'setup.exe' file and run the installation BEFORE the PC goes to the Startup Menu?

Or is there another way to get this PC to work? I don't care about the info on the PC now, I just want it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Batch files are run by Windows, so cannot be run before Windows boots.  Normally there is a key sequence you can press during POST (when you first turn on the machine) that will let you choose to boot from a CD.  Try F12 or Del - just hit them repeatedly as the machine first powers up.

Comment: Or try recovering the password [7 Free Windows Password Recovery Tools](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/passrecovery.htm)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hirensbootcd.org/ - Are you familiar with Hirens? I am unsure what you mean by "I cannot get the PC to install from the CD", but if you are able to live boot Hirens you can re-set the passwords required?

Ed

Answer (score 0):

I think your BIOS settings is set to 'quickboot'. Meaning that the default booting device is the first HDD, even if a CD is present. - Pressing F12 on the boot-screen often opens a menu, where you can select the CD/DVD as boot device. - If not, you must enter the BIOS and change the settings that 'allow other boot devices' or setup the 'boot priority'. - The terms might be different from one BIOS to another, but generally easy to understand. ;o)